# Android gradle build failed - duplicate entry

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

After implementing Firebase in app messages I've got problem with building my app. I added to my gradle file dependencies :

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.1.0'
```

and now I'm receiving an error :

```
Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Applications/LandLord/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/prod/release/0.jar] (Can't read [/Users/rg/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.android/annotations/4.1.1.4/a1678ba907bf92691d879fef34e1a187038f9259/annotations-4.1.1.4.jar(;;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate jar entry [android/annotation/TargetApi.class]))
Thread(Tasks limiter_5): destruction
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForProdRelease FAILED
```

after checking libs with gradle I have found that issue is caused by Foursquare SDK :

```
compile ('com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.0.3')
```

You can see that it looks like annotation module is duplicated but I tried to add         `exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'`
 and it didn't work.

Any help, please ?

Comment: Try : File -> InValidate Cache/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: been there, done that. Didn't help.

Comment: Try cleaning your gradle cache from `.gradle/caches` in your HOME. Your cached `annotation` library might have been currupted.

Comment: Checked, didn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have two same classes inside same package com.google.android.annotation. you can see on external library from android studio like this one.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qy9sS.png

So you will need to exclude one of them. Foursquare brings whole com.google.android:android into your dependencies graph.
Foursquare only have following dependencies:

```
\--- com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.0.3
 \--- com.google.android:android:4.1.1.4
      +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
      +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
      |    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
      |    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
      |    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
      +--- org.khronos:opengl-api:gl1.1-android-2.1_r1
      +--- xerces:xmlParserAPIs:2.6.2
      +--- xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c
      \--- org.json:json:20080701
```

So doing  `exclude group: "com.google.android", module: "android"` will work, but i think foursquare will need that dependencies. Instead you can exclude another dependencies that bring com.google.android:annotation. You can check this by printing dependencies graph:
./gradlew app:dependencies > dep.txt

On my case, it was bring by `+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.1`

So i will put

```
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.1") {
    exclude group: "com.google.android", module: "annotations"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever read the error message? Try to exclude `com.google.android`:

```
implementation ("com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.0.3") {
    exclude group: "com.google.android"
}
```

Comment: Sure I have. I also checked your solution. Didn't work :/

Comment: @Bartos there might be further duplicates.